# Error:(21, 30) No resource found that matches the given name when adding string-arrays Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, compiler-errors, android-studio

Ever since I added two string-arrays to my project I've been getting the "no resource found that matches the given name" error (referring to the string arrays I've added in) when I try to build my project. I know that its the string-arrays that are causing the problem because when I delete them my app works fine. Here is how I have declared the arrays in arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="units_array_values">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="units_array_entries">
        <item>Metric</item>
        <item>Imperial</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And here is how I declare the ListPreference that uses them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <EditTextPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
            android:label="@string/pref_location_label"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <ListPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_units_key"
            android:label="@string/pref_units_label"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_units_default"
            android:entryValues="@string-array/units_array_values"
            android:entries="@string-array/units_array_entries" />

 </PreferenceScreen>
```

Any idea what might be causing this problem? I'm really confused by this error since if I right click either of the string-arrays in the preference xml I'm taken to the implementation of the arrays in arrays.xml. It seems like Android Studio can find the arrays when I ask them to but not when it's building my app.

Answer (score 3):

Use `@string` instead of `@string-array` to get string-array from strings.xml:

```
 ...
 android:entryValues="@string/units_array_values"
 android:entries="@string/units_array_entries" />
```

If you are still getting issue then create an separate `array.xml` in `res/values/` and put all arrays in separate file from strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
<string-array name="units_array_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="units_array_entries">
    <item>Metric</item>
    <item>Imperial</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Now access both array in `ListPreference` as:

```
 ...
 android:entryValues="@array/units_array_values"
 android:entries="@array/units_array_entries" />
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I noticed that I'm also getting an error that says 'R' (as in R.id.xyz) cannot be resolved as a symbol. Again, this goes away when I delete the string-arrays.

Comment: @Adam: R only not resolved when we have any issue in xml files

Comment: Also, if I move the arrays into strings.xml instead of arrays.xml the Android Studio "auto correct" reports it as an error unless I say "@string-array" instead of "@string". That's strange, since I don't have an xml file called string-array. When I right click on @string-array it takes me to string.xml though.

Comment: @Adam:`dimens.xml` is directory ? then it's not valid and move all files from `dimens.xml` dir to `values`

Comment: I think that may have been added by a wizard at some point, or if I added it I forgot about it (very new to Android). Can I delete it? Or should I just move it so its one level higher in the values directory?

Comment: @Adam: move only .xml files from `dimens.xml` directory to `values` directory and if you are not using  dimens.xml values in application then you can delete it

Comment: Here's a clearer picture of the problem: http://imgur.com/A0Hgl0J. At the bottom it says "unknown resource type arrays", maybe that's a clue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68660/discussion-between-adam-and--k).

Comment: @Adam : sorry my mistake rename `array.xml` to `arrays.xml` and also move `pref_general.xml` in layout folder

Comment: @Adam: for more help see following code https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/res/layout/preference_screen.xml and https://github.com/jbeerdev/BrightHubCode/blob/master/res/values/arrays.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs if you just change

```
android:entries="@string-array/units_array_entries"
```

to

```
android:entries="@array/units_array_entries"
```

That should solve it. 
No need for a separate resource folder.